# Sharing a variable between C and C++ libraries dilemma

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a simple problem.
I have two libraries, one compiled in C, other compiled in C++, where the C library is linked and loaded by the C++ library. I need to declare a struct instance in the C library that both can read and write to. 
How do you accomplish this?

Thanks

EDIT: added that it's to be an instance of a struct, not just the declaration

Comment: Libraries are not a communication mechanism.

Comment: @unapersson He isn't using libraries as a 'communication mechanism'. He wants share data between libraries. Noting wrong with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a single header file which is included by modules in both the C and C++ libraries:

```
#ifndef YOURSTRUCT_H
#define YOURSTRUCT_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    struct YourStruct
    {
        // your contents here
    };
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
// UPDATE: declare an instance here:
extern YourStruct yourInstance;
#endif
```

This form of header file means that both compilers will be happy reading the header file and both will produce the same name mangling.

**Update:**
Then you need a module file.  Just the one.  Either a C file if it is to be included in your C library, or a C++ file if it is to be included in your c++ library:

```
#include "yourstruct.h"

YourStruct yourInstance;
```

Now any client of the global instance, whether it is a C client or a C++ client just has to `#include "yourstruct.h"` and reference `yourInstance`

**Update:**
As Matthieu points out you are better off passing pointers to instances around. eg.

```
#include "yourstruct.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void yourFunction(YourStruct* someInstance);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Mandatory Note: global variables are **evil**, consider passing parameters to functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use extern C linkage specification.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif 

    struct YourStruct
    {


    };
#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

Comment: Doesn't that just export the struct declaration? I want to share a struct instance, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Yes, but the extern "C" block works the same way with declarations of instances and functions.

Comment: @Andy Johnson: Thanks! Yes you are correct. A little hasty answer & I missed out on the macro gaurds. Made the modifications.

Answer (score 1):

```
extern struct YourStruct *yourstruct_instance;
```

In one of the headers should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Export an instance of the struct from your c library. Have the C++ library include a header file from the c library.

In a .h file in the C library:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) struct MyStruct
{
    // members
}
extern __declspec(dllexport) struct MyStruct myInstance;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In a .c file in the C library:

```
__declspec(dllexport) struct MyStruct myInstance;
```

Your c and c++ code can then manipulate `myInstance`.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article for more info. Also, try creating a new C++ dll project and check the 'export symbols' box. This creates a c++ dll with an an exported class and instance of that class. Doing the same in c for an exported struct is very similar.